# How to boot Slax on my notebook (CCE XLE-425)?

Tags: boot, drivers, slax

I have a 8GB flash drive with Slax 6.1.2 SO installed on it, so I can use that in almost all computers I use to access my files and programs with my configurations.

BUT I have one serious problem with my notebook: I cannot use Slax on boot (I can use it in VirtualBox 4.0.12 following @harrymc instructions on ["How to boot from a flash drive OS using VirtualBox?"](https://superuser.com/questions/318227/how-to-boot-from-a-flash-drive-os-using-virtualbox) question).

Perhaps it is something about drivers. I tried changing some bios settings and using some command on boot, but with no success. I would like to use it in that way because VirtualBox limitations...

Any help from you?

---

Bellow the HW config of my computer:

```
CCE XLE-425

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5800 @ 2.00GHz
Caption: Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13
L2 cache size: 2.00 KB
Manufacturer: GenuineIntel
Address width: 64

RAM size: 2.87 GB

Model: I40SI1
Manufacturer: OEM
OEM string: This is a SMBIOS 2.5 BIOS |Some of the structures are included |for demonstration purposes only
System type: x64-based PC

Monitor: Monitor Genérico PnP
Manufacturer: (Tipos de monitor padrão)
Screen height: 800
Screen width: 1280

Bios: Ver 1.00PARTTBL
Manufacturer: OEM
Version: ACRSYS - 6040000
Ver: 1.00PARTTBL
Release date: Jul 01 2009
SMBIOSBIOSVersion: 1.03.03CE
SMBIOSMajorVersion: 2
SMBIOSMinorVersion: 5
Bios features:
  ISA is supported
  PCI is supported
  Plug and Play is supported
  APM is supported
  BIOS is Upgradable (Flash)
  BIOS shadowing is allowed
  ESCD support is available
  Boot from CD is supported
  Selectable Boot is supported
  EDD (Enhanced Disk Drive) Specification is supported
  Int 13h - Japanese Floppy for NEC 9800 1.2mb (3.5, 1k Bytes/Sector, 360 RPM) is supported
  Int 13h - 5.25 / 360 KB Floppy Services are supported
  Int 13h - 5.25 /1.2MB Floppy Services are supported
  Int 13h - 3.5 / 720 KB Floppy Services are supported
  Int 13h - 3.5 / 2.88 MB Floppy Services are supported
  Int 5h, Print Screen Service is supported
  Int 9h, 8042 Keyboard services are supported
  Int 14h, Serial Services are supported
  Int 17h, printer services are supported
  Int 10h, CGA/Mono Video Services are supported
  ACPI is supported
  USB Legacy is supported
  LS-120 boot is supported
  ATAPI ZIP Drive boot is supported

Disk drive
Caption: WDC WD2500BEVT-00ZCT0 ATA Device
Description: Unidade de disco
Capabilities: Random Access
Supports Writing
  Manufacturer: (Unidades de disco padrão)
  Model: WDC WD2500BEVT-00ZCT0 ATA Device
  Size: 250 GB


Battery: I40SI1
Caption: Internal Battery
Chemistry: Unknown
Design capacity: 31.68 Watt-Hours
Design voltage: 14.40 Volts

Display configuration: SiS Mirage 3 Graphics

Video controller: SiS Mirage 3 Graphics
Adapter RAM: 128.00 MB
Video processor: SiS672 series
Availability: Running or Full Power

Physical memory
1. Capacity 2.00 GB
2. Capacity 2.00 GB

OnBoard devices
1.  Description SiS 7012 PCI Sound Chip
    Device type Sound

2.  Description SiS 191 EtherNet Chip
    Device type Ethernet

3.  Description SiS 7013 Modem Chip
    Device type Unknown

4.  Description SiS 7001 OHCI USB Chip
    Device type Unknown

5.  Description SiS 7002 EHCI USB Chip
    Device type Unknown

6.  Description SiS 180 SATA Control Chip
    Device type Unknown

Sound device
1.  Name    Dispositivo de High Definition Audio
```

Comment: I gave up and use that solution: [How to boot from a flash drive OS using VirtualBox?][1] 


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/318227/how-to-boot-from-a-flash-drive-os-using-virtualbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a bootable copy of PLOP bootmanager, boot from there and then connect your Slax live key. After that select the USB option from the menu and you should boot normally of your flash drive

http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html