# Installing Windows 8 from USB Stick on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8, bootable-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to boot from a flash drive OS using VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/318227/how-to-boot-from-a-flash-drive-os-using-virtualbox)

so I've got a bootable USB stick with windows 8 on it, and I need to install it as the guest OS on VirtualBox. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be supported.

Is there a way to install this? Closest thing I can figure is to make an .iso file of the USB drive, and then use that to install in VirtualBox.

any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Yup, make an ISO

Comment: See the following question and answer [How to boot from a flash drive OS using VirtualBox](http://superuser.com/questions/318227/how-to-boot-from-a-flash-drive-os-using-virtualbox) on SuperUSer