# Mount UFD to a VHD or an iso

Tags: windows-8, mount, hyper-v, bootable-media

Can I mount a live folder or a Removable USB drive as an iso or a VHD and present it to a Hyper-V VM to as a bootable device?

Is there any way to boot a Hyper-V VM off a Removable bootable USB device ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes. PFB answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a [patriot UFD](https://www.dateks.lv/en/cenas/usb-flash-diski/80657_patriot_tab_32gb_usb3_0). I used an [RMB-flip application](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_gibVObQlQvc/SC1jAZkTGXI/AAAAAAAAAAc/JEp_30VsP6w/s320/boot-it.png) for the controller of that UFD to convert it to a non-removable drive. Then mounted it to a Hyper-V VM as a passthru disk and booted from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vmdk file pointing to your USB Drive. This vmdk file can be be used in Virtualbox or VMPlayer.However I am not sure if Hyper-V VM support vmdk files.

Alternatively you can use [PLOP Boot Manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html) and try booting your USB Flash Drive

http://agnipulse.com/2009/07/boot-your-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/

[How to boot from a flash drive OS using VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/318227/how-to-boot-from-a-flash-drive-os-using-virtualbox)

http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/how-to-boot-from-usb-under-vmware-server

Comment: I know. But I am trying to achieve this in Hyper-V.