# Booting windows 7 on Virtual box from USB that doesn't contain iso

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, usb-boot

I have this USB key that contains windows 7 but the structure on it is like this

```
   bootmgr
   BOOT/
   EFI/
   Sources/
   zRCDIMAGE/
```

Now when I boot from usb on my physical computer it works fine, but i've been having problems getting it to launch on virtualbox. I've tried using plob linux iso to try to boot it but without any success. Would anyone know how I should proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just create a .iso of the contents and use that instead?

Comment: it totals 10 gigs

Comment: Why does that matter exactly?  Your not actually burning anything.  The .iso could be 100GB in theory.

Comment: Wouldnt there be problems with standards, I know you can burn a iso larger than 4 gigs, but wouldn't booting it be problematic?

Comment: I have created bootable double layer dvd's and blu-ray disks in the past.

Comment: Ok i'm making an iso of it right now

Answer (score 1):

Booting a VBox VM from USB is nigh on impossible. Even with Plop it usually fails.

I have had some luck by mapping the USB partition as a RAW device into the VM.

(See the VBox manual how to do that from the command line. Be sure to read the various caveats and warnings as well !)

Be VERY careful NOT to touch the USB device with any software from the host while doing that. You run a major risk of corrupting the USB drive.

(Tip: Instruct the virus-scanner on the host to completely exclude that USB drive from any scans. That will save you a great deal of potential issues. Sometimes this also helps to get Plop working.)

Answer (score 0):

Booting form USB IS possible!
Enable EFI and try booting till the USB-Device is detected.
Then choose the EFI file to boot from in the EFI shell or enter the EFI Boot Manager.
See a detailed explanation [here](https://superuser.com/a/1770767/501970).