# Boot VirtualBox VM from USB on macOS

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, boot-camp

I'm trying to save space on my Mac's internal hard drive by installing a Windows 10 virtual machine on a 128gb USB 3.1 USB, but I can't seem to figure out how to boot from the USB with VirtualBox.

I have been able to boot the ISO which just functions as an installer, but I want to boot the USB that has had a Windows-To-Go ISO burnt to it. Could someone explain?

I have already tried avoiding the virtual machine method all-together and making a UEFI bootable drive, but it keeps crashing with `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` in Windows 10 (I'm guessing this is something to do with how the USB is mounted during bootup as I have already installed the recommended drivers).

Comment: Virtual Box IS able to [boot directly from USB](https://superuser.com/a/1770767/501970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to boot from a bootable USB, you have to make a pass-through device.

This assumes you have USB Installer already created or an image of that installer as a file.

#### Step 1:  Create the Installation Media

Using `hdiutil` create a sparse (expanding) disk image with a size of 6GB

```
hdiutil create -size 8GB -fs FAT32 -volname "Win10-Install-Media" -type SPARSE ~/win10-installation-media
```

Next, mount the image

```
hdiutil mount ~/win10-installation-media.sparseimage
```

You will get a message that describes the layout of the drive image.  Pay attention to the disk identifier as you will need it for the next step.

#### Copy the install USB to the image

```
dd if=/path/to/USB/Installer of=/dev/disk#
```

The newly created image will need to be unmounted for the next step, so go ahead an unmount the disk.

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk#
```

#### Step 2:  Create the VMDK

To do this, we are going to use VirtualBox's "raw hard disk access" to create a pass through to the newly created drive image.

The syntax of the command is as follows:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename </path/to/file>.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/disk#
```

So, for our purposes, the command would be (note the escaped spaces)

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/Windows\ 10\ Install.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/disk#
```

The VMDK will be a very small file that simply points to disk you created in Step 1. Now you can attach the VMDK to your VM and boot from it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I keep getting error `hdiutil: create failed - Invalid argument` when trying the first step.

Comment: Doh!.  It's supposed to be `FAT32`.  Sorry for that..I was typing on my iPad and I think it autocorrected.